# Export makefile variable with dollar sign

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have two makefiles and I want to pass from Makefile1 a variable to Makefile2.

The problem is that this variable have a `$` inside of it.

Here is the files:

```
# Makefile1
RPATH1 = 12\$$34
export RPATH1

all:
    @echo RPATH1 "(Makefile1)" $(RPATH1)
    @make -f Makefile2 RPATH2=$(RPATH1)


# Makefile2

all:
    @echo RPATH1 "(Makefile2)" $(RPATH1)
    @echo RPATH2 "(Makefile2)" $(RPATH2)
```

When I run it, I get:

```
$ make -f Makefile1
RPATH1 (Makefile1) 12$34
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/make'
RPATH1 (Makefile2) 124
RPATH2 (Makefile2) 124
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/make'
```

I want to have a way to Makefile2 print `12$34` too.

What I may do?

Edit: I have discovered some way, but it's not very consistent. Usage in first Makefile is different than in second one.

```
# Makefile1
RPATH1 := '12$$$$34'
export RPATH1

all:
    @echo RPATH1 "(Makefile1)" $(RPATH1)
    @make -f Makefile2 RPATH2="$(RPATH1)"
    @make -f Makefile2 RPATH2="'12\$$\$$34'"


# Makefile2
all:
    @echo RPATH1a "(Makefile2)" $(value RPATH1)
    @echo RPATH2a "(Makefile2)" $(RPATH2)
    @echo RPATH2b "(Makefile2)" $(value RPATH2)


$ make -f Makefile1
RPATH1 (Makefile1) 12$$34
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/make'
RPATH1a (Makefile2) 12$$34
RPATH2a (Makefile2) 12151308134
RPATH2b (Makefile2) 12151308134
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/make'
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/make'
RPATH1a (Makefile2) 12$$34
RPATH2a (Makefile2) 12$34
RPATH2b (Makefile2) 12$$34
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/make'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution for passing variables manually:

```
override quote = '$(subst ','"'"',$1)'

all:
    @make -f Makefile2 RPATH2=$(call quote,$(value RPATH1))
```

---

Also, it's weird to see backslashes and quotes in Make variable definitions (in `RPATH1`).

Make itself ignores them, they're interpreted by the shell when printing the variable.

You might want to use `$(info` `)` instead of `echo`, which doesn't escaping. Or use my `$(call quote,` `)` when printing, to properly escape the contents.

---

> Could you put a complete example?

Sure.

```
# Makefile1
RPATH1 = 12\$$34'

override quote = '$(subst ','"'"',$1)'

all:
        $(info RPATH1 "(Makefile1)" $(RPATH1))
        @make -f Makefile2 RPATH2=$(call quote,$(value RPATH1))


# Makefile2

all:
        $(info RPATH2 "(Makefile2)" $(RPATH2))
        @true
```

```
$ make -f Makefile1
RPATH1 "(Makefile1)" 12\$34'
make[1]: Entering directory '...'
RPATH2 "(Makefile2)" 12\$34'
make[1]: Leaving directory '...'
```

Comment: Could you put a complete example? I'm not seeing this working as intended.

Comment: @AdrianodosSantosFernandes Sure, see edit.

Comment: It worked using my example. But when I put in the real use case it didn't worked.

```
LIB_PLATFORM_RPATH = -Wl,-rpath,$(1)

LIB_LINK_RPATH = $(call LIB_PLATFORM_RPATH,\$$ORIGIN/../$(1))

RPATH2 := $(call LIB_LINK_RPATH,lib)
```

Comment: I changed it to this to work: override quote = '$(subst $,$$$$,$1)'

Comment: @AdrianodosSantosFernandes Check if this still handles spaces and single quotes.